# Getting statistics (analytics) about number of users with rooted devices

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics

How can I get statistics about how many of my users have rooted phone? Does the Google/Firebase analytics produce such reports? (I don't have experience with Google Analytics or Firebase)

I was looking at previous stackoverflow articles, but it didn't help. Also I checked a bit in google but still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you have to do a manual action to access that information.

For example, you can write a function that detects rooted devices and send an event in the relevant function.

You can use the code below to detect rooted devices.

```
RootBeer rootBeer = new RootBeer(context);
if (rootBeer.isRooted()) {
    //we found indication of root - send firebase event
} else {
    //we didn't find indication of root
}
```

Library : `implementation 'com.scottyab:rootbeer-lib:0.1.0'`